# How to launch a method on all ng-click events AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have made a web application in Node.js that lets users manage their mongoDB database. I have several click events that do CRUD actions that change the status of the database. On each ng-click I call the corresponding function to do the CRUD action. The problem is that, in each of these functions I call the a method called refresh which updates the page so it matches the current database info. Is there a way, I can just hook up the refresh function to be called whenever a ng-click event has ended?

Examples

```
$scope.dropDB = function (DB) {
    $http.post('/dropDB', JSON.stringify({ 'DB': DB })).success(function (response) {
        refresh();
    });
};

$scope.addDB = function (DB) {
    try{
        var objson = JSON.stringify({ 'DB': DB }) ; 
        $http.post('/addDB', objson).success(function (response) {
            console.log("DB Added: ");
            refresh();
         });
    }catch(ex){
        alert("Not a valid input type");
    }
};
```

Comment: By `ng-click` you mean whenever `$http.post` is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Make wrapper factory for your `http` call

```
['$http', function($http) {
  return function(method, route, body) {
    var args = method === 'POST' ? [route, body] : [route];
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      return $http[method].apply(this, args).then(function(res) {
        refresh();
        resolve(res)
      }).catch(function(err) {
        reject(err);
      })
    });
  }
}];
```

Then you can use it in your controller

```
myFactory('POST', '/database', {foo: 'bar'}).then(function(res) {
  // at this point refresh() was already called
})
```